# C# Should I prevent an event to be unhooked twice?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

If an event is hooked and is unhooked later in the application then I try to unhook it again.
Should I prevent this ?

```
private void MyFunctionCalledWheneverIWant()
{
    // Second unhook : Should I prevent this ? How ?
    myObject.MyEventHandler -= MyEvent;
}

public void MyEvent()
{
    // First unhook
    myObject.MyEventHandler -= MyEvent;
}
```

Comment: No need as such, unhooking twice is allowed without resulting in exception

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unsubscribing twice doesn't cause a problem as @puneet and @MaartenVanSambeek noted. If you want to add a check you can do this by GetInvocationList and go through the list to verify if you have the subscription. If so unsubscribe.

```
if(MyEventHandler!=null)
{
    foreach ( Delegate existingHandler in  MyEventHandler.GetInvocationList())
    {
        if ( existingHandler == MyEvent)
        {
            myObject.MyEventHandler -= MyEvent;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be a good idea to check MyEventHandler ins't null, in case it doesn't have any delegates subscribed.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a problem to detach an event handler twice, if the event was only attached once, the second detach will do nothing.